# Sending Emails with an Application using Microsoft Graph API with 2FA on the accounts

Tags: c#, email, microsoft-graph-api

I need some help with the following issue, We recently added 2FA to our email accounts and we had code on using System.Net.Mail, which worked fine. but now we have 2FA turned on we need to authenticate before we can send messages.
I have decided to go with Microsoft Graph to authenticate and send emails.
I found some examples and have given permissions and can succesfully authenticate, but the application cannot send an email on behalf of the current user. I get the following error:

```
    Code: ErrorAccessDenied
    Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
    
    System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
    Status Code: Forbidden
    Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ErrorAccessDenied
    Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
    
       at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

I have set the Mail.ReadWrite.All, permissions and have consented as an admin for the organization. I know that the application has successfully authenticated as I am able to Upload files to SharePoint via the same program.

Permissions for Application:

```
Mail.ReadWrite
Mail.Send
Sites.Read.All
Sites.ReadWrite.All
User.Read
```

All permissions have been consented to by admin.

Below is the code where I have the program send an email to our support team with the from address as the current logged in user.

```
    var MAIL = new Microsoft.Graph.Message
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = new Microsoft.Graph.ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = Microsoft.Graph.BodyType.Text,
            Content = message
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Recipient>()
        {
            new Microsoft.Graph.Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = Email.SupportAddress
                }
            }
        },
        From = new Microsoft.Graph.Recipient()
        {
            EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress
            {
                Address = fromAddress
            }
    
        }
    };
    
    await graphClient.Me
        .SendMail(MAIL, null)
        .Request()
        .PostAsync();
```

It Errors when trying to Post the Request with Forbidden.
I cannot see what other permissions I must use to allow Sending Emails via the application.

Any help with identifying why the application can not successfully send on behalf of the User would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: For App context flows it doesn't know the meaning of me, so try this `await graphClient.Users["userid/UPN"]
        .SendMail(MAIL, null)
        .Request()
        .PostAsync();`

Comment: Ah, Thanks Shiva, That was what was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Please accept it as answer  by clicking the check mark so that it could be helpful to others having same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For App context flows it doesn't know the meaning of me, so try this.

`await graphClient.Users["userid/UPN"] .SendMail(MAIL, null) .Request() .PostAsync();`